# Samsung S4 mini LightSensor Event every 10ms

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I own a Samsung S4 mini with LineageOS 14.1 installed.
If I view the system log with "adb logcat" there is an entry every 10ms about reading the LightSensor, even if the device is in standby. I think that's unnecessary and will will empty the battery. Can anyone give an hint of how to stop this?

Thanks. Serge

```
...
12-01 12:38:46.455   586   664 D Sensors : LightSensor readEvents x = 22.000000, raw = 22
12-01 12:38:46.466   586   664 D Sensors : LightSensor readEvents x = 22.000000, raw = 22
12-01 12:38:46.475   586   664 D Sensors : LightSensor readEvents x = 22.000000, raw = 22
...
```